# Is there any concurrency package for C-language?

Tags: c, concurrency

I know Java and C# both have library package to support concurrency programming. Does anyone know whether or not there is library package for C? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

1. Qt QThread
2. pthread
3. MPI (for computations on multiple computers)
4. (more)

Answer (score 4):

At the lowest level, you have [pthreads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads), which give you threads, locks, condition variables, etc.  It's about as basic as you can get.  If your program uses a framework, it might provide its own threading primitives so you don't have to use pthreads directly.

1. [Qt Threading Support](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/threads.html)
2. [Glib threads](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/unstable/glib-Threads.html) (used by GTK)
3. [Boost threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/thread.html) (for C++)

Other packages provide higher-level concurrency operations that may be easier to reason about.

1. [Intel Threading Building Blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Threading_Building_Blocks)
2. [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP)
3. [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface)
4. [QtConcurrent](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtconcurrent.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is [`OpenMP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) which is supported by compilers like `icc`, `msvc` and `gcc` (at least).